# ssh, problem with headless device

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, headless

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a headless device. Since the last update and shutdown it is not possible to connect via ssh anymore. nmap shows the machine is up and in the network, all ports are closed. When I connect the Hard Drive of the headless device to my laptop, it is possible to connect from another machine. It seems it is somehow due to the different network card.

Comment: If you connect the HDD to your laptop (just mount it, don't boot from it) you can read the boot logs to investigate where the problem is.

Comment: Having same problem here after recent update. All other servers are running perfect except apache2 and ssh. The only way I have to get into my system ATM is by ftp

Comment: It's possible you're having issues with kernel and 3.13.0-30. As soon as I booted back into 29 everything was fine. Seriously considering downgrading to either 12.04 or 13.10 neither of which I ever had problems with